# Showing whether $\mathcal{F} = \lbrace f \mid \Re(f) > 0, 0 < f(0) < r \rbrace$ is normal

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show whether the family of holomorphic functions $\mathcal{F} = \lbrace f \mid \Re(f) > 0, 0 < f(0) < r \rbrace$ is normal, where $f$ is a function from the unit disk to the right half plane (where normality is defined by the existence of $\sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \sup_{k \in K} |{f(k)}|$ for compact $K$).

It isn't hard to see that the condition $0 < f(0) < r$ is necessary, since if we just let $\mathcal{F}' = \lbrace f \mid \Re(f) > 0\rbrace$, then given any $f \in \mathcal{F}'$, the sequence $f_n(z) = nf(z)$ is in $\mathcal{F}$ but clearly has no convergent subsequence, which is a contradiction by Montel. Conversely, if we consider some fixed $u$ and let $\mathcal{F}'' = \lbrace f \mid \Re(f) > 0, f(0) = u\rbrace$, we can easily show that $\mathcal{F}''$ is normal, since we can map the right half plane conformally to $D$ such that $f(0) \mapsto 0$, so we get the boundedness by the Schwarz lemma.

Intuitively, I would think that $\mathcal{F}$ would imply some sort of boundedness, but since we can't just map the right half plane to $D$ in a way that all values $(0, r)$ map to $0$, we can't easily use Schwarz to show this.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? How do I show that $|g(0)| < A$ (and where does $A$ come from?)

Comment: Also, I don't quite see how this implies normality.

Comment: previous comment was not quite correct; using $g=\frac{f-1}{f+1}$, for any sequence $f_n$ the corresponding $g_n$ (self maps of the disc) has a normally convergent subsequence by montel with limit either self map of the disc or $-1$ since the condition on $f(0)$ shows that it may not converge to $1$ (the limit is either a disc self map or a constant of modulus one but by the reality of $g(0)$ constant can be only $-1$ or $1$); then since $f=\frac{1+g}{1-g}$, it follows that $f_n$ has a convergent subsequence to a function that is finite ( may be identically zero) and that gives the result